# Schema for offline map editing and pass to production environment

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, spatial-database

I'm working with QuantumGIs and PostgreSQL/Postgis. So when I edit the layers, the changes are reflected on the DB.

The thing is I want to do some "offline" editing before committing the changes to the DB, as the DB is in production and serves Geoserver for displaying the maps on a website.

Anyone know a good schema to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot recommend a pure offline editing, since the data (and work) security is much better with your current approach. To my knowledge there is no solution within QGis, but the outside solution is simple

- clone your live DB to a 2nd stage one
- work on the stage DB
- clone the stage DB to the live DB (or update it with the changes, more complex )

Either write your own scripts or do a google search for deployment scripts. A very mature candidate is Capistrano http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capistrano, which was orig.  programmed for use with Ruby-on-Rails. Since you don't need all file operations, the DB functions are enough and simple to reach.